# Convert [u8;32] to AccountId

Tags: account

I am trying to call an extrinsic with specific AccoundId, I have considered two options

1. Generate AccountId from Key-Pair

   ```
   let caller = sr25519::Pair::from_string("//1", None)
                .unwrap()
                .public();
   ```
2. Hardcode accountId

   ```
   let caller:T::AccountId = "5GBNeWRhZc2jXu7D55rBimKYDk8PGk8itRYFTPfC8RJLKG5o".to_owned().into()
   ```

Generating the same AccoundId is important because there is an Origin check in extrinsic that AccountId should exit in Some_Storage of type Vec<T::AccountId>

```
benchmarks! {
    set_value {
    let caller = sr25519::Pair::from_string("//1", None).unwrap();
    }: _(RawOrigin::Signed(caller.public().into()),2)
}
```

Is there any way to generate AccountId from the above two ways or any other way?
Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the [frame_benchmarking::account](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_benchmarking/fn.account.html) function to derive accounts deterministically.
It is possible to vary them with a seed, if needed.

```rust
use frame_benchmarking::{account, whitelist};

const SEED: u32 = 1;

benchmarks! {
    set_value {

        let caller: T::AccountId = account("Alice", 0, SEED);
        whitelist!(caller);

    }: _(RawOrigin::Signed(caller), 2)
}
```

The `whitelist` macro invocation is important to make the signing part work.
Otherwise if you just need *a* fixed account, you can use the [whitelisted_caller](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_benchmarking/fn.whitelisted_caller.html) account.

Comment: I want to generate the same AccountId generated by pair, so basically I will need to convert sr25519::Public to AccountId.

Comment: `AccountId` is normally just a u64 for benchmarking, so that is not possible AFAIK. Can you not just insert the `AccountId` into the storage with `Some_Storage::<T>::append(id)`?

Comment: yeah, for now, I am referring to it from the storage. Thanks